# Hangout bot how to @mention user in a card message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts, google-chat

I've created a bot that is supposed to inform users from a group about the tasks they were assigned to. It is working well with the simple message using  but it's not working once put in a card message - I got "---" or "???" instead of mention. I tried to put it in different widgets: keyValue, textParagrap or header but it doesn't change anything. Does anyone know if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A review of the API description should have confirmed your suspicions - at this moment, you cannot mention a user via a Card message, only a simple message.

Per [Card Text Formatting](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#card_text_formatting):

> Inside cards, most text fields support basic text formatting via a small subset of HTML tags.

and

> Note that the text body of a basic message is parsed using a different markup syntax

The API Reference page on message formats for simple messages explicitly identifies how one mentions users in simple messages ([1](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#messages_that_mention_specific_users), [2](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#messages_that_mention_all_users))

Another hint comes when viewing the API descriptions of [`spaces.messages`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages) and [`cards`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards): the metadata associated with a `Message` includes [`Annotations`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#annotation) which include [`UserMentionMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#usermentionmetadata).
If viewing the specification for a `Card`, no such specification is observed. The description of a [text widget](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards#textparagraph) contains only the formatted text.

Thus, if you need to notify a particular user about the content of a card, you should either DM the card to the user, or mention the user in a simple message immediately before or after the card is sent.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine simple messages with cards in a single posting to achieve this.

For example, the following JSON will display a message with `@all` in the text above the card.  If you know the user id, you can change `<users/all>` to notify a specific user.

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "sections": [
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
              "keyValue": {
                "content": "<pre>ls -l</pre>",
                "contentMultiline": "true",
                "icon": "DESCRIPTION",
                "topLabel": "Executed Job"
              }
            },
            {
              "keyValue": {
                "content": "<pre><font color=\"#006400\">passed</font></pre>",
                "contentMultiline": "true",
                "icon": "BOOKMARK",
                "topLabel": "Status"
              }
            },
            {
              "keyValue": {
                "content": "<pre>5 milliseconds</pre>",
                "contentMultiline": "true",
                "icon": "CLOCK",
                "topLabel": "Elapsed"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "text": "<users/all> : Job `ls -l` *passed*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for particular one, <users/123456789> would work.
but the one have to join the group. Otherwise it will be blank.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).